# How to highlight concurrent sessions in same date and time by specific user in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: snapshot of concurrent session in excel]

As can be seen in the snapshot above: Sarah has concurrent sessions on 5/9/2016.

I would like to highlight the sessions concurrent on the same date with color codes for each date.

Please let me know if there is a formula for this.

Comment: Yes there is. You will have to look into conditional formatting and compare the date of those items.

Comment: can you please send me the steps for the above case?

Comment: What have you tried to make it work? In addition if you really want to unique colors for each pair you'd need to look into VBA, probably.